# Read Index (Table of Content) of word document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am interested to get the topic headings (say all lines with Heading 1 and Heading 2) from a word document. Using VBA you can parse thru every line in that document and verify the style; however this seems to be a tedious job. I believe that there should be some easy way of doing it. Any pointers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pointer --->

tempD = ActiveDocument.GetCrossReferenceItems(wdRefTypeHeading)

gives you a list of Headings in document.